# Hashing string values results in different outputs on Linux vs Windows in C++

Tags: c++, boost, hash, hashcode

I am trying to hash single `std::string` and `std::vector<std::string>` values. I am following the examples from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) and [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp). When the code is compiled and run on Windows vs Linux, I get different results.

The header file for `MyHasher.h` is as follows.

```
class MyHasher {
 private:
  MyHasher() = delete;
 public:
  static std::size_t hash(std::vector<std::string> ids);
  static std::size_t hash(std::string s);
  static void hashCombine(std::size_t &seed, std::size_t value);
};
```

The CPP file `MyHasher.cpp` is as follows.

```
std::size_t MyHasher::hash(std::vector<std::string> ids) {
  std::size_t seed = 0;
  for (auto id : ids) {
    std::size_t h = std::hash<std::string>{}(id);
    hashCombine(seed, h);
  }
  return seed;
}
std::size_t MyHasher::hash(std::string s) {
  std::size_t seed = 0;
  std::size_t h = std::hash<std::string>{}(s);
  hashCombine(seed, h);
  return seed;
}
void MyHasher::hashCombine(std::size_t &seed, std::size_t value) {
  seed ^= value + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2);
}
```

A sample program then runs as follows.

```
int main() {
  std::cout << std::to_string(MyHasher::hash("0")) << " | 0" << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::to_string(MyHasher::hash(std::vector<std::string>{"0"})) << " | 0" << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::to_string(MyHasher::hash(std::vector<std::string>{"0", "1"})) << " | 0 1" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

On Linux (g++ 7.4.0), the output is as follows.

```
2297668036269395695 | 0
2297668036269395695 | 0
10545066640295778616 | 0 1
```

On Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019, MSVC-14.0), the output is as follows.

```
12638135526163551848 | 0
12638135526163551848 | 0
1964774108746342951 | 0 1
```

Any ideas on this discrepancy?

What I really want is a way to always produce an unique hash output that is dependent on the input, but cross-platform and fixed width. The width is not important, per say, but as long as it is the same width regardless of the input(s).

Comment: Unrelated: `class MyHasher` looks a lot like a namespace.

Comment: OT: You should pass arguments to `MyHasher::hash` by constant reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the doc. of [std::hash](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash), it is explicitly mentioned that:

> The actual hash functions are implementation-dependent

…

> Hash functions are only required to produce the same result for the same input within a single execution of a program;

I'm a bit uncertain about a hash function which always returns identical hashs for identical input. I googled a bit but failed to find something which I would dare to present.

Assuming that the std library of MS VC++ and g++ may be different implementations, it cannot be expected to produce identical hashs for identical input.

Reading the second part of cite carefully, you even cannot expect that the same program results in identical hashs for identical input in distinct processes (e.g. when started, exited, and started again).

---

[Cryptographic hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) might be a solution:

> - it is deterministic, meaning that the same message always results in the same hash
> - it is quick to compute the hash value for any given message
> - it is infeasible to generate a message that yields a given hash value
> - it is infeasible to find two different messages with the same hash value
>     a small change to a message should change the hash value so extensively that the new hash value appears uncorrelated with the old hash value ([avalanche effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect))

[Checksums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum) are related to hash functions. For a checksum, it must be required to result in identical output for identical input (to be reliable).

So, a checksum implementation based on a hash function should match the requirement of OP as well.

The accepted answer to [SSE: Which hashing algorithm shoud I use for a safe file checksum?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/198665) recommends [SHA256 or SHA512](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2).

This remembered me that I recently heard that [git uses a variation of SHA-1](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/hash-function-transition.txt) but [git may use SHA256 as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60088126/7478597) as well which appears to me as similar use case to what (I assume) OP might have.

Comment: Suggested addendum (just to beat the point home): The solution to the problem is to provide your own underlying hashing algorithm so that you can be guaranteed of the same behaviour on any platform.

Comment: @user4581301 I did my best. (I must admit I'm no expert.) ;-)

Comment: You covered more ground than I would have. Plenty of options for people to try in there

Comment: I just noticed that your Cryptographic hash functions link goes to simple.wikipedia.org. If you change that to en.wikipedia.org, then the list of properties is expanded, and the first line is: `it is deterministic, meaning that the same message always results in the same hash`. So, I think that answers the question of identical hashes for identical inputs. :)

Comment: @Frodyne Thanks for the valuable hint. I reviewed my answer.