# Change git Repository Hash Function?

Tags: git, hash

I'd like to use `SHA-512` as the hash function within a `git` repository.  Is this possible without modifying the source code for `git` itself?  I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47838703/1923100) from years ago here on StackOverflow suggesting it was an upcoming feature at the time, but have been unable to locate documentation on it thus far.

Comment: You can technically create a repo that uses `sha256`, but it's still considered experimental. See the man page on `git init --object-format`

Answer (score 4):

I wrote [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47838703/6309) you mention, and detailed the reasons behind that change in "[Git is moving to new hashing algorithm SHA-256 but why git community settled on SHA‑256](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60088126/6309)"

The transition is still in progress, and explained in "[`Documentation/technical/hash-function-transition.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/hash-function-transition.txt)"

That document will give you a good idea of the steps necessary to be completed before Git is able to use a different hash.
Those steps are still very much in progress.

Comment: I don't suppose there are any updates on this @VonC?

Comment: @ScottishTapWater No, this is still a work in progress. It has not stopped though.

Comment: Thanks :) Appreciate you getting back to me